# error in the result of the execution of a web service java. ambiguous because it could not determine its class

Tags: java, web-services

sorry for my English..

I'm trying to run a web service in java
but at the time of the result (a string) jumps an error, it says:

the serializer / deserializer for the number of parameter: 0, name: "{http: // services /} consultarLibrosResponse" type "{http: // services /} consultarLibrosResponse" is ambiguous because it could not determine its class

the return type of the method of the web service I'm trying to run is of type String, I'm making a cast but does not work
I have not found something on the web
execution the service code is as follows

```
    ServiceFactory sf = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
    Service serv = sf.createService(
    new URL("http://localhost:8080/WSLibreria/libreria?WSDL"),
    new QName("http://servicios/", "libreria"));
    Call call = serv.createCall(
        new QName("http://servicios/", "libreriaPort"),
        new QName("http://servicios/", "consultarLibros")
    );
    String result = (String) call.invoke(
    new Object[]{ "novela" });
```

I appreciate your help.